# Recovering Terminated instances on Openstack

Tags: openstack

I've accidentally terminated a few instaces on my Openstack deployment. Any chance of recovering them at all ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible but there is an option to get data.

[Check here](https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/61857/how-to-recover-terminated-openstack-instance/).